# Save Avro Schema to Confluent Schema-Registry

Tags: avro, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I am trying to write a very simple schema to the registry using Postman, and have been having a very hard time getting it to register. Is it really this complicated just to register a simple schema which is only the first step in this whole process, or am I missing something here ?  The schema I am using is below:

```
    {
"schema":{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "User",
  "namespace" : "com.temp.avro.model",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "_id",
    "type" : "string"
  }, {
    "name" : "updatedDate",
    "type":"long",
    "logicalType":"timestamp-millis"
  }, {
    "name" : "createdDate",
    "type":"long",
    "logicalType":"timestamp-millis"
  }, {
    "name" : "applicationId",
    "type": ["null", "string"],
    "default": null
  },{
    "name" : "country",
    "type" : "string"
  }, {
    "name" : "bank",
    "type" : "string"
  }]
}
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Internal Server Error com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token\n at [Source: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream@774da834; line: 2, column: 1] (through reference chain: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.entities.requests.RegisterSchemaRequest[\"schema\"])\ncom.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token\n at [Source: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream@774da834; line: 2, column: 1] (through reference chain: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.entities.requests.RegisterSchemaRequest[\"schema\"])\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:148)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.mappingException(DeserializationContext.java:835)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:59)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:12)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:523)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:95)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.BeanPropertyMap.findDeserializeAndSet(BeanPropertyMap.java:285)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:248)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:136)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bind(ObjectReader.java:1410)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:860)\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase.readFrom(ProviderBase.java:810)\n\tat io.confluent.rest.validation.JacksonMessageBodyProvider.readFrom(JacksonMessageBodyProvider.java:65)\n\tat org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.invokeReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:260)\n\tat org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:236)\n\tat org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:156)\n\tat org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:74)\n\tat org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:156)\n\tat org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.readFrom(MessageBodyFactory.java:1085)\n\tat org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:853)\n\tat org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerRequest.readEntity(ContainerRequest.java:270)\n\tat org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.EntityParamValueFactoryProvider$EntityValueFactory.provide(EntityParamValueFactoryProvider.java:96)\n\tat org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParameterValueHelper.getParameterValues(ParameterValueHelper.java:81)\n\tat org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$AbstractMethodParamInvoker.getParamValues(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:127)\n\tat org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$VoidOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:143)\n\tat org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)\n\tat org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)\n\tat org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)\n\tat org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)\n\tat org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:308)\n\tat org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)\n\tat org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)\n\tat org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)\n\tat org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)\n\tat org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)\n\tat org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)\n\tat org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:291)\n\tat org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1140)\n\tat org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:403)\n\tat org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:386)\n\tat org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:548)\n\tat org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:489)\n\tat org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.doFilter(ServletContainer.java:426)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.handle(CrossOriginFilter.java:256)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.doFilter(CrossOriginFilter.java:219)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.handle(StatisticsHandler.java:159)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)\n"
```

Comment: Has your issue been resolved ? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 7):

The value for `schema` must be a string. Try to `JSON.stringify` your Avro schema, so that the JSON payload you would send to the schema registry is the following:

```
{
  "schema": "{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"User\",\"namespace\":\"com.temp.avro.model\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"_id\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"updatedDate\",\"type\":\"long\",\"logicalType\":\"timestamp-millis\"},{\"name\":\"createdDate\",\"type\":\"long\",\"logicalType\":\"timestamp-millis\"},{\"name\":\"applicationId\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"],\"default\":null},{\"name\":\"country\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"bank\",\"type\":\"string\"}]}"
}
```